# How to configure Camunda 7.10 (Wildfly full distribution) to work with Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, wildfly, camunda

I have downloaded the Camunda 7.10 (Wildfly full distribution), made some tests using the default H2 (in-memory) database and everything worked fine.

Then I configured the `standalone.xml` to use an Oracle 11g database.
As soon as I start the server with the `camunda-example-invoice-7.10.0.war` deployed, I got the exception:

```
12:12:45,570 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.camunda.bpm.platform.process-application-module."deployment.camunda-example-invoice-7.10.0.war".START: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.camunda.bpm.platform.process-application-module."deployment.camunda-example-invoice-7.10.0.war".START: Exception while invoking the @PostDeploy method
        at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.service.ProcessApplicationStartService.invokePostDeploy(ProcessApplicationStartService.java:223)
        at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.service.ProcessApplicationStartService.start(ProcessApplicationStartService.java:152)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.camunda.bpm.application.ProcessApplicationExecutionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.camunda.bpm.application.impl.ProcessApplicationLogger.processApplicationExecutionException(ProcessApplicationLogger.java:94)
        at org.camunda.bpm.application.AbstractProcessApplication.execute(AbstractProcessApplication.java:120)
        at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.service.ProcessApplicationStartService.invokePostDeploy(ProcessApplicationStartService.java:215)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.service.ProcessApplicationStartService$1.call(ProcessApplicationStartService.java:218)
        at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.service.ProcessApplicationStartService$1.call(ProcessApplicationStartService.java:215)
        at org.camunda.bpm.application.AbstractProcessApplication.execute(AbstractProcessApplication.java:117)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.camunda.bpm.engine.OptimisticLockingException: ENGINE-03005 Execution of 'UPDATE TaskEntity[0ec55ac9-77ed-11e9-a885-024251084739]' failed. Entity was updated by another transaction concurrently.
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.EnginePersistenceLogger.concurrentUpdateDbEntityException(EnginePersistenceLogger.java:134)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.handleOptimisticLockingException(DbEntityManager.java:498)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.checkFlushResults(DbEntityManager.java:450)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.flushDbOperations(DbEntityManager.java:366)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.flushDbOperationManager(DbEntityManager.java:324)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.flush(DbEntityManager.java:296)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.flushSessions(CommandContext.java:207)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.close(CommandContext.java:136)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:115)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.JtaTransactionInterceptor.execute(JtaTransactionInterceptor.java:60)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:69)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:32)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.TaskServiceImpl.claim(TaskServiceImpl.java:168)
        at org.camunda.bpm.example.invoice.InvoiceProcessApplication.startProcessInstances(InvoiceProcessApplication.java:157)
        at org.camunda.bpm.example.invoice.InvoiceProcessApplication.startFirstProcess(InvoiceProcessApplication.java:63)
        ... 17 more
```

This is my datasource configuration:

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine" pool-name="ProcessEngineDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
    <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
        jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(FAILOVER=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.1.2.3)(PORT=1551))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=testserv)(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=SELECT)(METHOD=BASIC)(RETRIES=5)(DELAY=3))))
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <driver>ojdbc7</driver>
    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
    <xa-pool>
        <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
        <no-tx-separate-pools>true</no-tx-separate-pools>
    </xa-pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>camunda</user-name>
        <password>camunda</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
</xa-datasource>
```

How to properly configure the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Camunda 7.10 by default uses [Jdbc Batch Processing](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.10/user-guide/process-engine/database/#jdbc-batch-processing) which works with Oracle 12c or newer. Since you are still on Oracle 11g you must set `jdbcBatchProcessing=false`:

> Another configuration - jdbcBatchProcessing - sets if batch processing mode must be used when sending SQL statements to the database. When switched off, statements are executed one by one. Values: true (default), false.
>
> Known issues with batch processing:
>
> - **batch processing is not working for Oracle versions earlier than 12.**
> - when using batch processing on MariaDB and DB2, jdbcStatementTimeout is being ignored.